# Why isn't Chromedriver handling a Angularjs route change

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Chromedriver to execute integration tests on a AngularJS web application running on a Wildfly application server running on Ubuntu hosted at AWS; the tests are written in Java and use the *PageInstance / PageObject* metaphor. The tests pass on my sandbox using the Chrome Browser and fail on the build machine using the Chromedriver browser.

The tests are failing with a *NoSuchElement no such element* error message. The error happens when the test clicks on a WebElement, *Tenant Admin*, with the intention to trigger a route change to transition from the *HomePage* view to the *TenantPage* view, see below for an error stack:

```
test0050DeleteTenant(com.dematic.labs.ngclient.TenantPageIT)  Time elapsed: 3.057 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.89)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307649 (bf55b442bb6b5c923249dd7870d6a107678bfbb6),platform=Linux 3.13.0-43-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.05 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'ip-10-40-217-10', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-43-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.Le0MBE}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=41.0.2272.89, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 8003e8020af650d40c165cd9492bbfab
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=TenantPageHeader}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:37)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.dematic.labs.ngclient.matchers.AttributeMatcher.attributeMatches(AttributeMatcher.java:188)
    at com.dematic.labs.ngclient.matchers.AttributeMatcher$16.matches(AttributeMatcher.java:114)
    at com.dematic.labs.ngclient.page.HasAttribute.matchesSafely(HasAttribute.java:29)
    at com.dematic.labs.ngclient.page.HasAttribute.matchesSafely(HasAttribute.java:10)
    at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.matches(TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.java:55)
    at com.dematic.labs.ngclient.TenantPageIT$$Lambda$29/276777344.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait$1.apply(FluentWait.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait$1.apply(FluentWait.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:175)
    at com.dematic.labs.ngclient.TenantPageIT.before(TenantPageIT.java:111)
```

Following is a detailed description of the set up, including code snippets.

**The (PageObject)HomePage relevant code:**

```
    @FindBy(id = "tadmin")
private WebElement tAdmin = null;
public WebElement gettAdmin() { return tAdmin; }

 public TenantPage tenantAdmin() {
  tAdmin.click();
  return PageFactory.initElements(driver, TenantPage.class);
}
```

**T**his is the *HomePage* HTML code being covered by the code above:

```
<div ng-controller='AuthorizeForAnyController'
 ng-show="authorizeForAny"
 iq-section="HomePageSection"
 id="HomePageSection">
<div class="container"
     iq-section-type="InstanceAdministration">Instance Administration
    <div iq-section_type-task="ShowTenantOperations">
        <ul>
            <li dl-authorize-for='administerTenants'><a id="tadmin" href="tAdmin">Tenant Administration</a></li>
            <li dl-authorize-for='administerTenants'><a id="tadminuseradmin" href="tAdminUserAdmin">Tenant Admin User Administration</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**N**otice the first anchor element, id=tadmin; this is the tAdmin element used to click. Following is the route used to trigger the expected view change that is not being observed and causing the tests to fail:

```
angular.module("app").config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true});

$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'Security/signin_prompt.html',
    controller: 'SigninController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'Security/signin_prompt.html',
    controller: 'SigninController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'Home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomePageController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/tAdmin', {
    templateUrl: 'Tenant/tenant.html',
    controller: 'TenantController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/tAdminUserAdmin', {
    templateUrl: 'Tenant/tenant.html',
    controller: 'TenantController'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

});

**F**ollowing is the integration test code that fails:

```
     // Navigate to home page, wait until it is loaded
    homePage = loginPage.login(INSTANCE_ADMIN_USERNAME, INSTANCE_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

    Matcher<? super WebElement> tAdminAnchor = new HasAttribute(HomePage.INSTANCE_ADMINISTRATION_ANCHOR_LINK_ENUM);
    getWebElementFluentWait(homePage.gettAdmin())
            .until((Predicate<WebElement>) tAdminAnchor::matches);

    // Navigate to tenant page, wait until it is loaded
    tenantPage = homePage.tenantAdmin();
    Matcher<? super WebElement> pageHeader = new HasAttribute(TenantPage.TENANT_ADMINISTRATION_CRUD_IQ_HEADER_ENUM);
    getWebElementFluentWait(tenantPage.getPageHeader())
            .until((Predicate<WebElement>) pageHeader::matches);
```

**T**he error is triggered by the second *getWebElementFluentWait* statement. It fails waiting for the TenantPage view to load; below is an HTML snippet of the  TenantPage view:

```
<div id="TenantPageHeader" iq-header="TenantPageHeader">Tenant Header</div>
```

**N**ote that the tests are waiting for the TenantPageHeader to be rendered and fail waiting for it.

**D**ebug statement showing the output of *driver.getPageSource()* suggest that the driver still has the HomePage (shown above). Also, debug statements indicate that the tAdmin anchor element is enabled, visible, with suitable width and height.

**A**n attempt to replaced the anchor element with a button linked to a controller which issued a **$location.$route('/tAdmin')** also fails similarly.

**M**y suspicion is that Selenium / Chromedriver are not handling the route transition leaving the original view in place leading to the test failure.

Thanks in advance for any insights anyone might be able to shed on this.

Comment: The problem has been fixed. A couple of weeks ago I renamed a number of HTML files (removed capitalization); somehow one of the files, the critical one in this particular instance, was renamed in my sandbox but not in Github!?